# Cerrar ventana modal en CSS

Tags: css

Mi código para cerrar el modal es:

Html:

```js
a.ventana-cerrar { 
  position: inherit; 
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  background-color: #333; 
padding: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff; 
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Js:

```js
a.ventana-cerrar {
     position: inherit;
     top: 3px;
     right: 3px;
     background-color: #333;
     padding: 7px 10px;
     font-size: 20px;
     text-decoration: none;
     line-height: 1;
     color: #fff;
    }
```

Y la venta no se cierra, qué tengo que cambiar o agregar para que funcione.

Comment: ¿Cuál modal? Por favor agrega el código respectivo.

Comment: el código solo es la declaración del estilo de un link. puedes editar la pregunta para la compresión pública.

Comment: podrias actualizar tu codigo? tienes css en ambos snippets!

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor que he probado para crear ventanas modales es jQuery. Puedes definir una capa cualquiera e identificar esa capa. Después, en un bloque script le pones que la capa sea modal y añades los eventos que tu capa deba tener en el momento que se abra o se cierre, por ejemplo si tuvieras que hacer una llamada ajax para cargar en tu capa modal algo más específico, pero que sólo te interesase mostrar si se abre la capa.

Ejemplo sencillo:

```js
$("#pinchar").click(function() {
    $("#unError").dialog("open");
});

$('#unError').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Error',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Vale',
        click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->

<div id="unError">
  Muestra un error modal
</div>

<div id="pinchar">
  Pincha aquí para mostrar una ventana modal
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

para cerrar el modal no se hace con css, si estas manejando bootstrap tu botón debería ser algo similar

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

para ver ejemplos [Modals bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: Y si fuera con js como sería?

Comment: Agrega el html de tu modal para entender como lo estas haciendo

Comment: @Jlcanizales  - Te sorprenderías lo que se puede hacer con puro css... [Modal SIN JS](https://codepen.io/maccadb7/pen/nbHEg)...

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a cerrar una ventana modal, lo mejor sería ponerle un width: 0; y un height: 0; y para darle ese efecto de desvanecimiento, darle un opacity: 0; y animar solo esa propiedad con transition. El position inherit no haría falta.

Acá tengo una ventana modal hecha con puro CSS, por ahí te ayude:
[Venta modal css](http://codepen.io/KaoruMishimaru/pen/VvLjOa)